# How to use BeautifulSoup to retrieve the URL of a tarfile

Tags: python-3.x, regex, beautifulsoup

The following webpage contains all the source code URLs for the LFS project:

https://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/systemd/chapter03/packages.html

I've wriiten some python3 code to retrieve all these URLs from that page:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import sys, os

#url=sys.argv[1]
url="https://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/systemd/chapter03/packages.html"
exts = (".xz", ".bz2", ".gz", ".lzma", ".tgz", ".zip")

response = get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
  if link.get('href'):
      for anhref in link.get('href').split():
          if os.path.splitext(anhref)[-1] in exts:
              print((link.get('href')))
```

What I would like to do is input a pattern, say:

pattern = 'iproute2'

and then print the line that contains the iproute2 tarfile

which happens to be:

https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/iproute2/iproute2-5.12.0.tar.xz

I've tried using match = re.search(pattern, text) and it finds the correct line but if I print match I get:

<re.Match object; span=(43, 51), match='iproute2'>

How do I get it to print the actual URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use `.string` property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.string) (returns the string passed into the function).

**Code Example**

```
txt="https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/net/iproute2/iproute2-5.12.0.tar.xz"

pattern = 'iproute2' 

match = re.search(pattern, txt) 

if match:   # this condition is used to avoid NoneType error
    print(match.string)

else:
    print('No Match Found')
```

Comment: great, just what the doctor ordered!

Comment: Glad you liked it! Would you mind to upvote the answer?